# Unhandled exception / Access violation as soon as I use OutputDebugStringW() on a variable

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm writing a program which splits off into threads, each thread is timed, and then the times are added together in `total_time`.

I protect `total_time` using a mutex.

The program was working fine, until I added 'OutputDebugStringW', which is when I started getting these Unhandled exception / Access violation errors.

```
for (int loop = 0; loop < THREADS; loop++)
{
    threads[loop] = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, MandelbrotThread, &m_args[loop], 0, NULL);
}
WaitForMultipleObjects(THREADS, threads, TRUE, INFINITE);
OutputDebugStringW(LPCWSTR(total_time));
```

Within each of these threads, it does some calculation which it times, EntersCriticalSection, adds the time taken to `total_time`, `LeaveCriticalSection`s, then ends.

I tried adding `EnterCriticalSection` and `LeaveCriticalSection` around `OutputDebugStringW()` but it didn't help to fix the error.

Any thoughts?

**Update 1:**

Here is the MandelbrotThread function -

```
unsigned int __stdcall MandelbrotThread(void *data)
{
    long long int time = get_time();
    MandelbrotArgs *m_args = (MandelbrotArgs *) data;
    compute_mandelbrot(m_args->left, m_args->right, m_args->top, m_args->bottom, m_args->y_start, m_args->lines_to_render); 
    time = time - get_time(); 
    EnterCriticalSection(&time_mutex);
    total_time = total_time + time; 
    LeaveCriticalSection(&time_mutex);
    return 0; 
}
```

m_args are the sides of the set to be rendered (so the same for every thread), and the line to start on (y_start) and the number of lines to render.

Comment: show us the MandelbrotThread function and what's args and how it is used in the function?

Comment: What type is `total_time`, and why do you think that *casting* it to a `LPCWSTR` is a good idea?

Comment: It's a long long int, and I just searched online and an example suggested that if you wanted to output an int like that you should do OutputDebugStringW(LPCWSTR(int))

Comment: Whoever wrote that example should be shot, as it's **quite** wrong. >_>

Answer (score 4):

reinterpret_cast'ing a number to a string will certainly shut up the compiler, but will not make your program magically work. You need to convert it, using sprintf, or preferrably boost::lexical_cast (although I'm guessing the latter's not an option for you).

```
WCHAR buf[32];
wsprintf(buf, L"%I64d\n", total_time);
OutputDebugStringW(buf);
```

Comment: Now getting a 'cannot convert parameter 1 from 'WCHAR [32]' to 'LPSTR' error

Comment: Then you're either calling `OutputDebugStringA` instead of `OutputDebugStringW`, or `sprintf` instead of `wsprintf`.

Comment: WCHAR buf[32];
    wsprintf(buf, L"%d\n", total_time);
    OutputDebugStringW(LPCWSTR(buf));

Comment: @ShimmerGeek, I don't know what to tell you, it works for me. Also, you left the unnecessary and dangerous cast in. In any case, perhaps the error is coming from somewhere else?